# Componente hijo no reconoce Angular Material,

Tags: angular

Hola comunidad tengo un problema y llevo días investigando y no puedo solucionarlo, ojala puedan ayudarme.
Estoy usando componentes hijos en una interfaz de administración, el problema es al querer usar angular material, no lo reconoce mi componente, aunque ya lo importe en su modulo correspondiente, dejo evidencia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En los componentes que no son hijos si se reconoce angular material.
Alguien sabe como solucionar este problema ???

Comment: Bienvenido @David! Con solo esa información va a ser difícil poder ayudarte. Podrías añadir en alguna plataforma online tu código (al menos una estructura básica) para poder ver con mayor detalle tu aplicación e intentar ayudarte. Yo uso [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/), pero vale cualquiera con la que puedas crear un proyecto angular. Puedes editar la pregunta todas las veces que necesites y añadir más información. Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te mencionaron dificil precisar el problema al no tener tu **codigo** ni   tu **confIguracion**
Sin embargo **si la estructura es solida si esta bien configurada** y como  me intereso por ngx-datatable la cual nunca habia usado  te muestro una configuracion que no trae problemas

> Probe una aplicacion que tenga Angular Material
> Icon+"@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^20.0.0", En una estructura padre
> hijo y con esta configuracion no hay problemas

```js
// angular.json
"styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "./node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/themes/material.scss",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
```

**No importar en** /* styles.scss */-->*@import '~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/themes/material.scss';*

Padre

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { AboutRoutingModule } from './about-routing.module';
import { AboutComponent } from './about.component';
import { LinksComponent } from './about/links/links.component';
import { InfoComponent } from './about/info/info.component';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgxDatatableModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AboutComponent,
    LinksComponent,
    InfoComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
   // FormsModule,
    //MatFormFieldModule,
 
    MatIconModule,
    NgxDatatableModule,
    AboutRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class AboutModule { }
```

about-routing.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AboutComponent } from './about.component';
import { InfoComponent } from './about/info/info.component';
import { LinksComponent } from './about/links/links.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AboutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'links',
        component: LinksComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'info',
        component: InfoComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AboutRoutingModule { }
```

about-routing.module

```js
// package.json
{
  "name": "ng-zone",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^20.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "sse.js": "^0.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
}
```

uno de los hijos info.component.html

```js
<p>info works!</p>
<mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example home icon">home</mat-icon>
```

index.html debe contener

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Tambien agregue codigo para la tabla en componente padre podes ver el codigo completo en **github** en [github ruta about](https://github.com/nestdanchia/NgZone/tree/main/src/app/about)
que reconoce a mat-icon y a la tabla me intereso porque no habia probado a ngx-datatable por lo cual en github para ngx-datatable use un codigo de apuntes el cual debo actualizar pero comprueba que Angular reconoce tanto a Angular material como a ngx-datatable en la estructura
**Otro problema** que puede darse es si usate iconos personalizados mal configurados tenes este tutorial si es el caso aunque no creo ya que no deberian mostrarse en ningun componente [iconos personalizados](https://www.zentica-global.com/es/zentica-blog/ver/tutorial-de-iconos-de-angular-material-11-con-ejemplos-del-mundo-real-6073ad9eb2cfc)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @nestdan, me ayudaste mucho con esta solución y efectivamente la estructura que tenia en mi app-routing.module.ts esta mal, lo cambie a tu estructura y ya reconoce material. te agradezco nuevamente tu apoyo.

Comment: Si debia ser algun motivo de ese tipo por eso conteste con una estructura para mi adecuada Si consideras que la respuesta es adecuada recorda seleccionarla como tal asi se da por cerrada la busqueda saludos